# all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing a .NET 4.0 console app that

1. Opens up a connection Uses a Data Reader to cursor through a list of keys
2. For each key read, calls a web service
3. Stores the result of a web service in the database

I then spawn multiple threads of this process in order to improve the maximum number of records that I can process per second.

When I up the process beyond about 30 or so threads, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.   This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Is there an Server or client side option to tweak to allow me to obtain more connections fromn the connection pool?

I am calling a sql 2008 r2 DATABASE.

tHx

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a design issue.  What's your total record count from the database?  Iterating through the reader will be *really* fast.  Even if you have hundreds of thousands of rows, going through that reader will be quick.  Here's a different approach you could take:

Iterate through the reader and store the data in a list of objects.  Then iterate through your list of objects at a number of your choice (e.g. two at a time, three at a time, etc) and spawn that number of threads to make calls to your web service in parallel.

This way you won't be opening multiple connections to the database, and you're dealing with what is likely the true bottleneck (the HTTP call to the web service) in parallel.

Here's an example:

```
List<SomeObject> yourObjects = new List<SomeObject>();

if (yourReader.HasRows) {
    while (yourReader.Read()) {
        SomeObject foo = new SomeObject();
        foo.SomeProperty = myReader.GetInt32(0);
        yourObjects.Add(foo);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < yourObjects.Count; i = i + 2) {
    //Kick off your web service calls in parallel.  You will likely want to do something with the result.
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2] {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => yourService.MethodName(yourObjects[i].SomeProperty)),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => yourService.MethodName(yourObjects[i+1].SomeProperty)),
    };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

//Now do your database INSERT.
```

Comment: how can I avoid having multiple connections? If I have multiple thread reusing a single connection, then it is possible that thread B may attempt to use the connection before thread A receives a response from using the connection. Are you suggestion ASync calls? What if I queue up too many requests, won't I start to loses requests? That sounds like a significant coding complication to account for. Back to the original question!how do I increase the the of connections that I can make?

Comment: @Chad - You can change the max pool size in your connection string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx.  I still think you're taking the incorrect approach to this problem.  The bottleneck is likely not in the database hit, but rather the web service hit.

Answer (score 0):

Opening up a new connection for all your requests is *incredibly* inefficient. If you simply want to use the same connection to keep requesting things, that is more than possible. You can open a connection, and then run as many `SqlCommand` commands through that one connection. Simply keep the ONE connection around, and dispose of it after all your threading is done.

Comment: I see your point, but don't DataReaders each need their own connection?

Answer (score -1):

Please restart the IIS you will be able to connect

Comment: not going to help him solve this problem.. it will just keep happening